# Cannot access '<component_name>' before initialization while using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the below code that is producing the `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Foo' before initialization` error:

```js
import styled, { css } from "styled-components/macro";

const Foo = styled.div``;

export default function App() {
  return <Foo css={css``} />;
}
```

Reproduction is available here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-golick-s3ofx0?file=/src/App.js

The project is built using Create React App.

May someone help me understand why is this erroring?

Comment: importing from `styled-components` instead of `styled-components/macro` works for me in the CodeSandbox

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam then you lose the `css` property functionality

Comment: Then maybe you can use two separate imports then `import styled from "styled-components";
import {css} from "styled-components/macro";`